# Why are JS-added elements styled different from those at page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation where sometimes elements are loaded at page load, and sometimes they are generated by JavaScript at a later date, nothing fancy there. However the dynamically genrated elements are spaced apart noticeably different in Chrome, FireFox, and Safari.

Below is an HTML page where one chunk of elements is in the DOM at page load and an exact copy of those elements is added by JavaScript after page load. For some reason the JS-added elements (those in `#added-late`) are styled different from those in `#exists-at-page-load` despite all styling and layout being the same.

**Question**: Why do the statically generated elements, those in `#exists-at-page-load`, have extra space around them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
      .dark-section-header {
        background-color: #222;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

      .dark-section-header div {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }

      .dark-section-header .track-menu {
        outline: 1px dashed #f00;
      }

      .dark-section-header .play-button {
        outline: 1px dashed #0f0;
      }

      .dark-section-header .star-button {
        outline: 1px dashed #77f;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="exists-at-page-load">
      <div class="dark-section-header">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
        <div class="track-menu"></div>
        <div class="star-button"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="added-late"></div>

    <script>
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById( 'added-late' ).innerHTML =
          '<div class="dark-section-header">' +
            '<div class="play-button"></div>' +
            '<div class="track-menu"></div>' +
            '<div class="star-button"></div>' +
          '</div>';
      }, 0 );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnr6z/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either have javascript insert whitespace between the divs:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById( 'added-late' ).innerHTML =
    '<div class="dark-section-header"> ' +
      '<div class="play-button"></div> ' +
      '<div class="track-menu"></div> ' +
      '<div class="star-button"></div> ' +
    '</div>';
}, 0 );
```

Or ensure your HTML does not:

```
<div id="exists-at-page-load">
    <div class="dark-section-header">
        <div class="play-button"></div><!--
     --><div class="track-menu"></div><!--
     --><div class="star-button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/vWsyF/) every combination of js and spacing.

Comment: Well damn. The problem started with a template, so I didn't even think about that. Turns out the template engine on the server was printing out pretty html, and the client was printing compact html. Thanks!

Comment: Went with a 5th option: float the elements. Making sure an extra space either did or didn't exist around the elements felt hackish, so I floated the elements left to get past the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are displayed as inline-block the line breaks are causing them to have whitespace

If I change your static divs to

```
  <div class="play-button"></div><div class="track-menu"></div><div class="star-button"></div>
```

whitespace goes away